# I am trying to do Hacker Rank Automation not selecting the desired element

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

> I am trying to submit the hackerRank website challenge through
> automation using puppeteer. After the solve challenge button is
> clicked the code goes on next page but doesn't select the the checkbox
> element i.e 'Text against custom input'

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const url = "https://www.hackerrank.com/auth/login";

(async function () {
  try {
    const browserInstance = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: false,
      slowMo: true,
      args: ["--start-fullscreen"],
      defaultViewport: null,
    });
    let newTab = await browserInstance.newPage();
    await newTab.goto(url);
    await newTab.waitForSelector("#input-1");
    await newTab.click("#input-1");
    let email = "some-email.com";
    await newTab.type("#input-1", email, {
      delay: 50,
    });
    let password = "some-password";
    await newTab.waitForSelector("#input-2");
    await newTab.click("#input-2");
    await newTab.type("#input-2", password, {
      delay: 50,
    });
    await newTab.click('button[data-analytics="LoginPassword"]', { delay: 50 });
    await waitAndClick('a[data-attr1="algorithms"]', newTab);
    await waitAndClick('input[value="warmup', newTab);
    let allChallenges = await newTab.$$(
      ".ui-btn.ui-btn-normal.primary-cta.ui-btn-line-primary.ui-btn-styled",
      { delay: 50 }
    );
    await questionSolver(allChallenges[0], newTab);
    console.log("Total Questions", allChallenges.length);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
})();
async function questionSolver(challenge, page) {
  await challenge.click();
  let inputIsClicked = await waitAndClick(".checkbox-input", page);
  return inputIsClicked;
}

async function waitAndClick(selector, cpage) {
  await cpage.waitForSelector(selector);
  let selectorClicked = cpage.click(selector);
  return selectorClicked;
}
```

> [image: the selected input is not getting selected]

Comment: It could possibly be because of your selector. Maybe you could share the outer html for the checkbox, it might help figure out why it is not being clicked. Also, your posted script has the username and password visible, maybe you would want to remove that!

Comment: input is disabled

Comment: What is this app supposed to do?

Comment: it is suppose to first login and then select algorithms section and then select solve challenge and solve that particular question and then submit it

Comment: @ZainabShaikh Did you read all the comments?

Comment: Yes I read all the comments

Answer (score 1):

> This is the solution that worked for me after updating the
> questionSolver Function as below

```
async function questionSolver(challenge, page, answer) {
      await Promise.all([challenge.click(), page.waitForNavigation()]);
      await waitAndClick(".checkbox-wrap", page);
      await page.waitForSelector("textarea.custominput");
      await page.type("textarea.custominput", answer, { delay: 10 });
    }
```